# Fetch realtime data from database using CubeJs

Tags: reactjs, cube.js

I'm using `cubejs` with `React`. I want to display real time data.

I tried using React lifecycle methods & state  , where the `<QueryRender>` component is triggered every 2 seconds. But it does not work.

Comment: You'll have more success with your question (and the answers you get) if you include some of the code you've tried and how your results are different from what you expected.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.
Please read [ask]. Then [edit] your question and add the code you've tried so far.
Be precise; "It does not work" is not a helpful problem description.
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can switch transport to Web Sockets:

```js
import cubejs from '@cubejs-client/core';
import WebSocketTransport from '@cubejs-client/ws-transport';

const cubejsApi = cubejs({
  transport: new WebSocketTransport({ authentication: CUBEJS_TOKEN, apiUrl: 'ws://localhost:4000/' })
});
```

And use react hooks subscriptions:

```js
import { useCubeQuery } from '@cubejs-client/react';

const Chart = ({ query }) => {
  const { resultSet, error, isLoading } = useCubeQuery(query, { subscribe: true });

  if (isLoading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  if (error) {
    return <pre>{error.toString()}</pre>;
  }

  return <LineChart resultSet={resultSet}/>;
};
```

To learn more: https://cube.dev/docs/real-time-data-fetch

Comment: @RashiqKodakkad Could you please elaborate on this? I believe it should go as separate question.